# How to Split String with , operator within brackets

Tags: java

I want to split a string with ',' operator. The original string look like following

```
input : decode(test,0,nvl(test,0),1)

My expected output:
decode(test
0
nvl(test,0)
1
```

I tried following program

```
String input = "decode(test,0,nvl(test,0),1)";
String[] arr = input.split(",");
```

Help me to solve above issue

Comment: What happened to the final parenthesis after `1` ?  I think you really need a parser to handle this in the general case.

Comment: If you split a string with the split(",") , you are going to get all the substrings that are separeted by "," in the original string so nvl(test,0) is not in the output of the split(",").

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
String arr[ ]= "decode(test,0,nvl(test,0),1)".split ("nvl\\(test,0\\)");
```

result

```
arr[0] == "decode(test,0,"
arr[1] == "nvl(test,0)"
arr[2] == ,1
```

now split `arr[0]` and `arr[2]` using `split(",");`

Comment: split regex should be like this : String arr[ ]= "decode(test,0,nvl(test,0),1)".split("(?<=nvl\\(test,0\\))|(?=nvl\\(test,0\\))");

Comment: Even easier: `String arr[] = {"decode(test", "0", "nvl(test,0)", "1"};`